# Why it cannot convert return expression of type?

Tags: swift, generics

I try to return constant `result` in `test2` method but the compiler throws error. Why?

```
public enum TestResult<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
}

struct TestModel {
}

class Test {
    func test1() -> TestResult<Any> {
        let obj = TestModel()
        return TestResult.success(obj)
    }

    func test2() -> TestResult<Any> {
        let obj = TestModel()
        let result = TestResult.success(obj)
        return result
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `TestModel` to `Any`:

```
func test2() -> TestResult<Any> {
    let obj: Any = TestModel()
    let result = TestResult.success(obj)
    return result
}
```